# Identical particles placed on the energy levels of a 1D harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, identical-particles

If the particles are 6 spinless bosons, would they tend to occupy the ground state together and make the lowest total energy of the system $E=6E_0=3 \hbar \omega$?

And If the particles are 6 spin 1/2 fermions, by Pauli's exclusion principles, would the 3 pairs of fermions occupy the first three lowest states($n=0,1,2$) and make the lowest total energy $E=2E_0+2E_1+2E_2=\hbar \omega + 3\hbar \omega +5\hbar \omega = 9\hbar \omega$?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your statements are correct. If the particles are not interacting, the ground state for $N$ bosons is $\frac{N}{2}\hbar \omega$. For N fermions, allocating 2 particles for each energy levels gives the ground state energy of $\frac{N^2}{4}\hbar \omega$ for even $N$ and $\frac{N^2+1}{4}\hbar \omega$ for odd $N$.